# Is lighter-than-air flight possible in animals?

Tags: humans, flight, genetic-engineering

Is it possible for a human to be genetically altered to be able to fly, but instead of wings, they use internal cavities filled with a lighter-than-air gas (possibly hydrogen) which, paired with hollow bones and reduced weight, enables them to fly simply by flapping their arms? I don’t mean that they’re actually floating up and up, but just light enough that they can fly like a balloon with wings.

Comment: A human has an internal volume of about 70 liters. If all the internal volume of a human was filled with hydrogen, that would provide a lifting force of about 70 grams or 2 ½ ounces.

Comment: D’oh! Bugger it!